# Angular CLI Generate Library with SASS

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I have an **Angular6** app that I am trying to create a library for. I was able to generate a library project but when I generate the component for the library, Angular CLI is creating it with **.css** files.

How can I get it to create **.scss** files?

Here are the commands I'm using to create the project:

```
ng new example-app --style=scss
rename example-app example
cd example
ng generate library example --prefix=exam --style=scss
ng generate component test --project=example
```

The `--style=scss` option on the `ng generate library` command does not have an effect, I still get CSS files in my test component folder.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can fix it by overriding `schematics` for your project in your `angular.json` like in the example below:

```
"example": {
    "root": "projects/example",
    "sourceRoot": "projects/example/src",
    "projectType": "library",
    "prefix": "exam",
    "schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "styleext": "scss"
      }
    },
 ....
}
```

or you can set this value via angular-cli like so:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

After that try to generate component, it should have `scss` extension.

EDIT (replace `styleExt` with `style`):

As per this closed ticket https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2248 with new version of Angular CLI `styleExt` has been replaced with `style` - I tested it in two libraries that are using Angular anf Angular CLI versions 8.