# SCSS with angular 6 library

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

Is there any way to use SCSS with angular 6 library feature?

If I run this command

```
ng generate library karam --style=scss
```

I'm getting an error

> Schematic input does not validate against the Schema:
>   {"style":"scss","entryFile":"public_api","prefix":"lib","skipPackageJson":false,"skipTsConfig":false}
>       Errors:
>
> Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(style).

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818889/angular-cli-generate-library-with-sass

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can use scss with Angular 6+. To include scss support to already created angular 6+ project we need to following command:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

This will add

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
```

in your angular.json file (with 6+ version .angular-cli.json file is no longer available)

Comment: where is the styles.scss file for this??